# Prevent browser-sync log data in firebug console

Tags: firefox, gulp, firebug, browser-sync

I often use gulp and its plugin [browser-sync](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/).
Every time i open firebug console tab, i see its full of logs like :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1457523519574-0 200 OK ۳ms browser...11.1.js (line 2)
```

I can use clear button but logs are interminable! they will appear twice.is there any persistent way to ride of these(browser-sync) logs?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Just uncheck the option *Show XMLHttpRequests* within the [*Console* panel's options menu](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Options_Menu).

[image: *Show XMLHttpRequests* option within Firebug's *Console* panel]

Though note that this will disable the logging for **all** XMLHttpRequests, (aka AJAX requests).

There is currently no way to filter out specific logs. There are already two enhancements requests for that: [issue 4507](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/4507) and [issue 6835](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/6835) targetting Firebug 2, but as Firebug 3 will be built upon the DevTools, it is probably wiser to follow the DevTools related requests. The closest one to your issue is [bug 905978](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=905978) to filter out messages for blackboxed sources, but I've also filed [bug 1102797](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1102797) some time ago for allowing to blackbox sources from within the *Console* panel and [bug 1255311](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1255311) right now for ignoring specific log messages.

Comment: thanks. you mean there is no way to disable this annoying flood of browsersync logs?  :( . i need my ajax requests logs

Comment: Unfortunately there is currently no way to filter specific logs. I've updated my answer to describe the current situation in more detail.